# return more then one JSON object in the same response and parsing it

Tags: c#, jquery, json

i have the following code: (simplified for readability)

#### C#

```
        foreach(DataRow dRow in myDS.Tables[0].Rows){
            Company myCompany = new Company();
            myCompany.id = int.Parse(dRow["id"].ToString());
            Companies.Add(myCompany);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Companies));
        Response.End();
```

#### jQuery

```
$.getJSON('ajax.aspx?what=' + $('input[name="what"]').val() + '&where=' + $('input[name="what"]').val(), function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        var myCompany = new function () {
            this.id = val.id;
        }
        Companies.push(myCompany);
    });
});
```

Now, i have another object in the C# code, which is named `Cities`
and i would like to return it in the same request.

something like

```
Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Companies));
Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Cities));
Response.End()
```

and offcourse parse it on the Client side.

how can i do something like that?

Comment: wrap those two collections (`Companies`,`Cities`) into one object, and than serialize this object. `{"companies":{...},"cities":{}}`

Comment: @Marek that needs to be an answer l:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the two properties into an anonymous object:

```
var result = new { Cities = Cities, Companies = Companies };
Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result);
Response.End();
```

Or if you are using some old .NET version which doesn't support anonymous objects you could define a wrapper class:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public IEnumerable<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
Wrapper result = new Wrapper();
wrapper.Cities = Cities;
wrapper.Companies = Companies;
Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(wrapper);
Response.End();
```

Also fix your AJAX call as you are not properly url encoding your parameters:

```
var data = { 
    what: $('input[name="what"]').val(), 
    where: $('input[name="what"]').val() 
};
$.getJSON('ajax.aspx', data, function (data) {
    $.each(data.Companies, function (index, val) {
        var myCompany = new function () {
            this.id = val.id;
        }
        Companies.push(myCompany);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Object` containing both collections like this:

```
{
"Cities": { ... Cities Collection ... },
"Companies": { ... Companies Collection ... }
}
```

So create one Object like

```
[Serializable]
public class Output {
    Collection<City> cities;
    Collection<Company> companies;
}
```

then will this object with data and output it